# RawData not implemented for f64

Tags: rust

I am trying to use ndarray to calculate dot products, and am getting compilation errors that I don't understand.

My basic function is

```rust
use ndarray::{ArrayD, ArrayBase};

pub fn cosine<L>(v1: &ArrayBase<f64, L>, v2: &ArrayBase<f64, L>) -> f64 {
    let x: f64 = v1.dot(&v2) / (v1.dot(v1) * v2.dot(v2)).sqrt();
    return x
}

pub fn cosine2(v1: &ArrayD<f64>, v2: &ArrayD<f64>) -> f64 {
    let x: f64 = v1.dot(v2) / (v1.dot(v1) * v2.dot(v2)).sqrt();
    return x
}
```

which fails to compile:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `f64: ndarray::data_traits::RawData` is not satisfiedchgraph                  
 --> src/simple.rs:3:1
  |
3 | / pub fn cosine<L>(v1: &ArrayBase<f64, L>, v2: &ArrayBase<f64, L>) -> f64 {
4 | |     let x: f64 = v1.dot(&v2) / (v1.dot(v1) * v2.dot(v2)).sqrt();
5 | | }
  | |_^ the trait `ndarray::data_traits::RawData` is not implemented for `f64`
  |
  = note: required by `ndarray::ArrayBase`
```

If I comment out `cosine`, I get an error from `cosine2`:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `dot` found for reference `&ndarray::ArrayBase<ndarray::data_repr::OwnedRepr<f64>, ndarray::dimension::dim::Dim<ndarray::dimension::dynindeximpl::IxDynImpl>>` in the current scope
 --> src/simple.rs:9:21
  |
9 |     let x: f64 = v1.dot(v2) / (v1.dot(v1) * v2.dot(v2)).sqrt();
  |                     ^^^ method not found in `&ndarray::ArrayBase<ndarray::data_repr::OwnedRepr<f64>, ndarray::dimension::dim::Dim<ndarray::dimension::dynindeximpl::IxDynImpl>>`
```

(and two more copies for the other dot products).  Why can the second version not find the method? It seems that `ArrayD` is a type based on `Array`, which is in turn a type based on `ArrayBase`, so `ArrayD::dot` should be an existing method.

I only need to be able to pass an `ArrayD`, so I am happy with a version of either that works.

The relevant parts of my Cargo.toml are

```
[dependencies.ndarray]
version = "0.13.1"

[features]
default = ["ndarray/blas"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the data type of `ArrayBase` is not indexed by the data type, but a `RawData` wrapper of the data type. Second of all, `dot` requires the `Dot` trait to be implemented. So, you should add these both to the trait bounds:

```rust
use ndarray::linalg::Dot;
use ndarray::{ArrayBase, ArrayD, RawData};

pub fn cosine<D, L>(v1: &ArrayBase<D, L>, v2: &ArrayBase<D, L>) -> f64
where
    D: RawData<Elem = f64>,
    ArrayBase<D, L>: Dot<ArrayBase<D, L>, Output = f64>,
{
    let x: f64 = v1.dot(&v2) / (v1.dot(v1) * v2.dot(v2)).sqrt();
    return x;
}
```